# Why Don't PC Boards Act Like Capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, pcb

If capacitors are just two conductive components sandwiching an insulator, then why aren't all PC board, or at least their traces, considered capacitors?

Comment: See [Parasitic Capacitance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_capacitance) (Wikipedia). Also related questions: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/56574/2028, http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/98372/2028

Comment: who said PCBs weren't like caps? they simply exhibit a very low non-uniform capacitances

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are, but only noticeable in very high frequencies (microwave wavelength or GHz).

Comment: That depends on applications, some smaller frequency circuits, in boards that have high length traces should consider the capacitance of the traces.

Comment: If by very high frequencies you mean a few hundred kilohertz. High Trace/Bus capacitance can cause issues in even low speed 100khz i2c for example.

Comment: On a multi-layer board, I think internal power and ground planes can have useful values of capacitance.